# object HTMLInputElement attr is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, input

I'm trying to get an input id from an array, but not sure if I am getting the data correctly or whats going wrong, because I need to get the id attribute to make some operations. First of all, I create dynamically this:

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type        : 'hidden',
    name        : 'id_products[]',
    value       : product_id,
    id          : 'id_'+product_id,
    readonly    : 'readonly'
}).appendTo('#form);
```

Then, I get the array in this way:

```
var selectedIDs = $('[name="id_products[]"]');
```

After that, if the length of selectedIDs is greater than 0, I use a for cycle to get the elements. But I need the id attribute (or the value of the input) from the current element:

```
if(selectedIDs.length > 0) {
    //There's at least 1 selected product

    for(var j=0; j < selectedIDs.length; j++)
    {
        var id_temp = selectedIDs[j].val();//.attr("id");
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But firebug says: [object HTMLInputElement].val() is not a function (obviously the same with attr()). Any ideas?

Comment: Dumb question -- are you sure that jQuery is getting loaded?

Comment: yes, jQuery is getting loaded

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ZGW2y/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `$(selectedIDs[j]).val()` or `selectedIDs[j].value`

JQuery function on native DOM Element won't work

http://jsfiddle.net/N2HAS/1/

Comment: It will work on inputs or any other HTML Element that has `value` attribute (for `val()`) but you have to convert it to a JQuery object first using `$()` syntax